# Change input width for file upload if empty image CSS

Tags: css, image, input, width

I would like to make the width larger of the input[type=file] if an image has not yet been uploaded. Here is what I've been trying:

```
input[type=file] img[src=""] {
width: 300px;
}
```

The input[type=file] and img[src=""] work when alone but I can't get them to work together.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're going for, but it sounds like this may be something you would want to handle server-side.

Comment: No, using CSS. Trying to make the area you can click larger to upload an image if there is no image yet uploaded.

Comment: Maybe see [this link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/custom-file-input-styling-webkitblink/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
input[type="file"] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 300px;
}
```